# Central limit theorem rate of convergences for different distributions

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

A famous fact in statistics is that for any i.i.d. random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac1n \sum_iX_i - \mu\right)$$
approaches $N(0,\sigma^2)$ as $n\to\infty$.

This is true for all random variables, but what I haven't been able to find much about is the rate at which this happens. Presumably for fatter tailed random variables the rate is much slower than for something like a $\chi^2$.

**My first question** is whether the "central limit rate" is known for something like $\chi^2$ and then a fat-tailed one like the log-normal.

**Secondly**, I would like to know if for a given $n$, there exists an (easy to construct) distribution such that $\sqrt{n}\left(\frac1n \sum_iX_i - \mu\right)$ is far from $N(0,\sigma^2)$ in some sense.